# Not receiving email sent using MessageUI framework

Tags: objective-c, messageui

I am using the MessageUI framework to send an email but I never receive that email when sent.

I am importing `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`

and then I have the following code

```
- (void)emailFile
{
if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    UIAlertView *cantSend = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Device not configured to send email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
       [cantSend show];
    [cantSend release];
} else {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailView setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"matthew.inman@cdl.co.uk"]];
    [mailView setSubject:@"Test"];
    [mailView setMessageBody:@"This is a text message" isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
}
}
```

and

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
if(error) {
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [errorView show];
    [errorView release];
} else {
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Sent Mail");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved: 
            NSLog(@"Mail Saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail Cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail Failed");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I get the message "Sent Mail" in the console but I like I said I never receive the email that I am sending.

I have gone through the apple documentation and can't find anything that helps can anyone else help me please. I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the outgoing mail box of the email you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are testing on a device, email will not be sent via the simulator.

Comment: I am using the Simulator, I will have to go get a test phone from the testing department. Thanks that was a great help.